# mysql query on column "serialNo" only returns the first row

Tags: php, mysql, casting

I have a mysql database on repairs to some major brand name appliances.  I know that it is likely among the various manufacturers that serial numbers will a string of numbers and letters.  Some likely relatively short, and others longer.  In any event the code I have at present will return only the first row, when I know there are additional rows with similar serial numbers.

The user is presented with a dialog that contains two inputs.  The first is a select box with options: `serialNo`, `techID`, `fname`, and `surname`. Once the option is selected, then the user can enter the appropriate response into an `input type=text`.  The text input is laundered through a function:

```
function test_input2($data, $connector) {
  if (!empty($data)) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);//
    $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($connector, $data);
    return $data;
  }
}
```

Next there is a query to get the count:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM tech WHERE serialNo LIKE'$id'";
```

Followed by the mysql query:

```
$sql = "
SELECT * FROM Acme.tech t
LEFT JOIN employees e
ON t.techID = e.EID
AND t.serialNo = '$id'";
```

Where `$id` is the serial number input by the user.
For testing I entered 12.
I know there are at least 3 records that start with "12": 12, 123456789, and 12A.
I've tried casting the input as a string in a couple ways:

```
$id=strval($id)
$id=(string)$id
```

For the purpose of pagination, additional code is added along the way to add the sort order and limits:

```
$sql = "
SELECT * FROM Acme.tech t
LEFT JOIN employees e
ON t.techID = e.EID
AND t.serialNo = '$id'
ORDER BY $mySort
LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

I was expecting to see the three examples I mentioned above: 12, 123456789, and 12A returned. I had tried a `LIKE` operator but not in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: please show also the code where you fetch data

Comment: *there are at least 3 records that start with "12"; 12, 123456789, and 12A.* But only in one of them the value EQUAL to "12". All another starts from, but not equal to. Use  `AND tech.serialNo LIKE '$id%'` instead.

Comment: 1. Move your filter/predicate to a WHERE clause instead of hamfisting it into your ON clause of your join. 2. Use a `LIKE` operator not an `=`. `SELECT * FROM Acme.tech
LEFT JOIN employees
ON tech.techID = employees.EID
WHERE tech.serialNo WHERE '$id%'"` 3. Don't actually run that statement as-is in php. Properly [bind your parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) so you aren't leaving yourself open for a sql injection attack. ESPECIALLY because that `$id` is derived from user input.

Comment: Thanks JNevill, but I sanitize input before it ever gets into a query.  Aslo, I had tried the LIKE operator but not in a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use SQL LIKE Operator

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Acme.tech LEFT JOIN employees ON tech.techID = employees.EID WHERE tech.serialNo LIKE '$id%'";
```

Comment: I had thought the LIKE operator would have returned all three of the examples I listed.  Anyway, it works.